# Django Rest Framework - Fill model field with previous entry value

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm starting to build a REST API with Django for study purposes and I have encountered an obstacle.

I have the following model:

```py
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 36)
    class_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    timestamp = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    last_timestamp = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

and a serializer:

```py
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['timestamp', 'last_timestamp']

    def create(self, validated_data, **kwargs):
        validated_data['timestamp'] = int(datetime.timestamp(datetime.now()))
        #validated_data['last_timestamp'] = ...
        return ExampleModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

I would like to fill the `last_timestamp` field with the `timestamp` value of the last entry that matches with the `class_type` of the current one.

Using the psycopg2 lib a simple solution could be:

```py
last_entry_query = 'SELECT max(id) FROM example_table WHERE class_type = %s' % current_type
get_timestamp = 'SELECT timestamp FROM example_table WHERE id = (%s)' % last_entry_query

cur.execute(get_timestamp)
try:
    ts = cur.fetchone()[0]
except:
    ts = 0
```

and use the `ts` value to add to the next entry. I'm new to Django and DRF, but I assume that is a proper way to do that correctly or at least more pythonic, if anyone could help it would be amazing.

Comment: `ExampleModel.objects.filter(class_type=validated_data["class_type"]).latest("-timestamp").last_timestamp` ?

Comment: This is pretty what I'm looking for, thanks for your reply. Would you bother to explain what the `latest` method expects as param or paste here the reference?

Comment: Django [***`latest(...)`***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#latest)